# What does it mean when a semicolon occurs in a makefile target's prerequisites?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've run into this syntax in a Makefile that I'm modifying:

```
some_target: ;

another_target: ...
```

What does the semicolon mean in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an [*empty recipe*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Recipes), which is used if you want to prevent the target from being assigned implicit recipes.